# Changing site web address

Tags: site

How can change the web address of the site ?

I want to change the web address shown on the screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8gp2.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information required i.e

- Do you want change the Address of Site collection which is root level.

Then you need a need new DNS entry which point to correct WFE. After that you have to update the AAM settings and IIS bindings.

- If this is path based Site collection and want change the url

Then you have to copy the exiting site collection to desired URL. You can do it either take the Backup of Site collection and then restore it with new url

Or Use the COpy-SpSite to copy it new location with in same web application.

- If the site collection is HNSC Collection then

Create New DNS entry and use Set-SPSiteUrl to set URL.